# BigQuery: create view with comments added to the top of the query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to create a view in BigQuery that also shows comments such as the author, date created etc.

But if I try this in the UI the comments are left out.
Is there a way to do this in the BigQuery UI?
Or are there other ways using bq client or python, or ...?

So for example if I run this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `my_project_id.my_dataset.my_view_name`
AS
-- this is my important comment. This will be a long and extensive comment.
SELECT 1 as column_a
;
```

BigQuery will not show the comments in the view when the UI is used to create that view:

[image: bq query not showing comments at the top of the query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First create the view without the comment.
- Then edit the sql of that view you just created and add the comments then.

See screenshots below.

**Choose Edit Query:**

[image: edit view query to add comments]

**Choose Save view:**
[image: after you've added the comments to the sql of the view, then choose Save View]

Answer (score 1):

Bigquery is skipping the *"---- this is my important comment. This will be a long and extensive comment."* because it is treated as a comment on the SQL query and it is not treated as a separate string to be included in the creation of view.

Another option is to use `bq` [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#bq) as shown below.

```
bq mk \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--expiration 3600 \
--description "This is my view" \
--label organization:development \
--view \
'-- this is my important comment. This will be a long and extensive comment.
SELECT 1 as column_a ' \
your-dataset.your-view
```

My sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the python API you can do as follows:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

bq_client = bigquery.Client()

view_id = "my_project_id.my_dataset.my_view_name"
view = bigquery.Table(view_id)

query = """
-- this is my important comment. This will be a long and extensive comment.
SELECT 1 as column_a
"""

view.view_use_legacy_sql = False
view.view_query = query

# if your view already exists
bq_client.delete_table(view)

# your query will now show the comment at the top
bq_client.create_table(view)
```

This results in the following view:

[image: bigquery view created with python with comments at the top]

See also: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#python